# Apostrophe in a possessive appears as an open-single-smart-quote instead of a closed one

Tags: posts, visual-editor

Copy & paste the following in the html post editor:

```
<em>John</em>'s
```

Then click preview button and see the results. It will be:

> John‘s

This is grammatically incorrect. It should be:

> John’s

It should always be a closed apostrophe. Any solutions to this? Obviously, the `<em>` tag conflicts the quote transformation.

I'm guessing [wptexturize()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize) does the quote transformations? Shouldn't it strip the tags first before interpreting the text...?

Comment: I just actually took a look at this, strangely `wptexturize()` should do its job like you expect it. Because this is the [match](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L134) and this the [replacement](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L67) - if I understand the code correctly. Example at [regex101 tester](https://regex101.com/r/nP2yB9/2). Sorry, still no real help, just confusion.

Comment: @ialocin Thank you for the research, one step closer to potential solution.

Comment: Bingo @Christine Cooper, another years-long outstanding bug uncovered - https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18549 - you're good at this! The offending line is 129 in formatting @ialocin I think (although you could argue `wptexturize()` is one long offending line...) - if the regex's changed to eg `'/(?<=\A|[([{"\-]|&lt;|' . $spaces . ')\'(?!s\b)/'` (to not match 's on its own) then this problem at least goes away...

Comment: @bonger Not again!... :D Thank you very much for posting this and bringing some clarity into the problem. I guess all we can do is to hope that they will care enough to implement a fix for this in core level sometime within the next decade or two.